# How to connect postgresql database to a maven project?

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc

I am developing a GIS project with the help of Geo Tool on maven. In that project I need to connect a PostgreSQL database to my maven project. If I connect a normal java project to PostgreSQL in NetBeans then there is no problem because I am adding a jar file of jdbc-postgresql driver to the library of the project.
But in case of maven project there is no library folder in which I could add the jdbc-postgresql driver, and the dependency folder of the maven project does not allow to add any jar or any library in it.

How we can use postgresql database in a maven project?

Comment: You need a maven dependency containing the postgresql driver.  You should not manually work with jar files when doing maven projects.

Comment: Share your pom.xml file you using

Comment: try this <dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

Unlike a normal java project that you copy or just throw the jar of the driver in the `lib` file, in Maven you use dependecies for that.

When you create a new Maven project you're going to notice there's a file called `pom.xml` and that's where you will throw your dependecies.

Here's the PostgreSQL driver dependency for Maven, add this in your `<dependencies></dependencies>` tag:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
```

Here's a link to the page in case you want a different version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql

Here's an example of how a `pom.xml` looks like, this is from a Spring Starter Project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Julian.... I have done it....                                                                                      I am making a GIS maven project in Geotool so how we can display a shape file from the postgresql database in geotool JMapFroam or JMapPane. Presently I can display the shape file from the file path, but I want to display this shape file from the postgresql database. So I can run spatial queries here.

Comment: No problem man. If you could evaluate the question, please do it. I'm glad to hear that you got it done.